# How to count number of objects detected in TFL Detect?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I have a model running on Tensorflow Lite for object detection in an Android device. Is there any way I can get the model to display the total number of object detected?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please take a look at how to ask a question guideline before posting a quesiton. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. This question need a lot of details in order for someone else to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [TFLite Object detection ref app](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android), the maximum object detected is 10. See the code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/ff4ddd4609f76d8b7d085033a9b4cd9a3c6d26bd/lite/examples/object_detection/android/lib_interpreter/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/detection/tflite/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java#L60).

If you want to know if the raw detected objects of the model, check the fourth output of the model, [num of detections](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/object_detection/overview#output_signature). See the code comments [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/ff4ddd4609f76d8b7d085033a9b4cd9a3c6d26bd/lite/examples/object_detection/android/lib_interpreter/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/detection/tflite/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java#L214-L220).